# Double Eeeek! 'Contact Us' link on 404 pages has strange characters in it!

Tags: bug, status-completed, 404-not-found

If I go to a 404 page on one of the StackExchange sites:

- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/404
- https://askubuntu.com/404
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/404

...and I click on 'Contact Us', my email program launches with the following address:

> team%2b**XXX**%40stackexchange.com

...where 'XXX' is the name of the site. I doubt that the email address is supposed to have escaped characters in it.

Comment: Note: this doesn't happen in FF4 - only in Chrome.

Comment: It also works correctly in Safari 5.0.4

Comment: I can't think of a good reason to encode those characters, but then again, I can't think of a good reason not to *decode* them either. Double-bad FTL!

Comment: Works fine on Chrome 12.0.725.0 dev.

Comment: I have Chrome 11.0.696.34 beta.

Comment: I see nothing wrong in my Chrome 10.

Comment: @John: What OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 ^^^

Comment: @John: Weird... I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's no reason for those characters to be encoded. Fixing!

Comment: Wow... I noticed this when I sent my (first!) email to the team a couple days ago, but I thought it was by design...